# XCode compiler warning: 'class' may not respond to 'method'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to get rid of a certain warning that keeps popping up.

This is part of my WordListTableViewController.m

```
#import "WordListTableViewController.h"
#import "XMLReader.h"
@implementation WordListTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [superviewDidLoad];
    NSDictionary *status = [_mainDictionary retrieveForPath:@"Dealers"];
}

@end
```

The XMLReader.h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface XMLReader : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate]] >
{
    NSMutableArray *dictionaryStack;
    NSMutableString *textInProgress;
    NSError **errorPointer;
}
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryForPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
+ (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
@end

@interface NSMutableDictionary (XMLReaderNavigation)
- (id)retrieveForPath:(NSString *)navPath;
@end
```

The warning I'm getting is:

*warning: Semantic Issue: 'NSDictionary' may not respond to 'retrieveForPath:'*

It does actually respond just fine, but I cannot figure out how to organise my headers so that the compiler would know what will respond...

Would really appreciate some help on this :)

Answer (score 4):

Well, your category `NSMutableDictionary (XMLReaderNavigation)` was added to NSMutableDictionary, and not NSDictionary. As it is, at runtime the method *does* exist on your actual allocated object, so it is invoked successfully. From the point of view of the compiler though, NSDictionary in fact does NOT respond to the *retrieveForPath* method.

Comment: Oh god, that's embarrassing :D
Thanks!

Comment: Hah! All my 'embarrassing' moments in this development 'thing' would fill a book! Good luck!

Comment: The funny part is that it'll work at runtime due to coincidence;  there is never an instance of either NSDictionary or NSMutableDictionary in your app.  There is a subclass of both that is instantiated for either and the instance is configured appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, the category you've provided extends NSMutableDictionary, whereas the object you're sending message to is an instance of NSDictionary class.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to import your category for your WordListTableViewController.m

```
#import "NSMutableDictionary+XMLReaderNavigation.h";
```